# Error in using " " and ' ' in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SELECT statement in my android SQLite as:

```
String query = "SELECT * from LoggedInEmails where " + LOGGED_EMAIL + " = " + email;
```

The logcat says there is error near "=". 
I tried doing:

```
String query = "SELECT * from LoggedInEmails where " + LOGGED_EMAIL + " = " + '"email"';
```

The use of "" and '' in android SQLite always confuses me.
Please help me figure out the error.

I'm really sorry if this isn't a standard question.

Comment: maybe `String query = "SELECT * from LoggedInEmails where " + LOGGED_EMAIL + " = '" + email + "'"`;

Comment: You should try  with `"SELECT * FROM LoggedInEmails  WHERE LOGGED_EMAIL ='"+ email +"'"`

Comment: you need to add single quote in string values

Comment: Instead of concatenating strings (which is costly and can be used for SQL injection), you should be using parametric queries (**?**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query As below. Expecting   `LOGGED_EMAIL` is the variable holding the column name :

```
String query = "SELECT * from LoggedInEmails where " + LOGGED_EMAIL + " = '" + email+"'";
```

You can checkout [`lang_keywords`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) to know more about keywords.

Answer (score 1):

1. Properly use ***`DOUBLE-SINGLE`*** Quotes.
2. Make sure, you set proper **`Table attributes`**.

You should try with

```
   String query ="SELECT * FROM LoggedInEmails WHERE " + LOGGED_EMAIL + " = '" + email + "'";
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Run**.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query!

```
"SELECT *" + " FROM " + LoggedInEmails + " WHERE " + LOGGED_EMAIL + "='" + email+ "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you want to enter a string value in SQL query you must surround it with single quotes ' character like this:

```
'email@some.com'
```

When writing java code Strings must surround with double quotes " character like this:

```
"email@some.com"
```

If i want to write SQL query in java code i have to use both rules. some thing like this:

```
String sql = " 'email@some.com' ";
```

Now lets imagine that we store email@some.com in a variable called email. so i change my code to this:

```
String email = "email@some.com";
String sql = email;
```

This code is not the same as above one, because it has no single quotes ' . I just add one single quotes to it's left and one single quotes to it's right but don't forget that each single quotes should be surrounded with double quotes to java accept it as a String data type:

```
String email = "email@some.com";
String sql = "'" + email + "'";
```

Not Lets fix your code:

```
String query = "SELECT * from LoggedInEmails where " + LOGGED_EMAIL + " = " + "'" + email + "'";
```

When you get used to it, you can write a better one like this: (just remove " + " after = )

```
String query = "SELECT * from LoggedInEmails where " + LOGGED_EMAIL + " = '" + email + "'";
```

How ever instead of writing hard code query use `query()` method of `SQLiteDatabase` class. Take a look at this:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#ReadDbRow

Good luck.